# How to pass a variable via script to the terminal command line and ensure that it does not contain escape strings?

Tags: ruby, terminal, sh, tshark, escaping

I am new to Ruby and most things related to the terminal. I am trying to make a script that would return information about RTP streams from a Wireshark trace file. I am implementing it in a way that simply creates a new trace file with only the packets that match the SSRC. Problem is when I pass the SSRC variable in the command that the script will execute I get an error saying that on line 1 the command "-w" was not found.

I don't quite understand what exactly is causing a new line to appear so it is hard for me to try anything really. I attempted to do some variatons of | sed 's///' but nothing I tried seemed to work.

My Ruby code;

```
stream = "0xb6143376"

`tshark -r #{file_name}.pcapng -d udp.port==#{src_port},rtp -2 -R 
rtp.ssrc == #{stream} -w #{file_name}_stream1.pcapng`
```

Terminal output;

```
tshark: Syntax error.
sh: line 1: -w: command not found
```

So I expected the script to finish and at the end I would have a new trace file with only the packets that match 0xb6143376 SSRC. What I get instead is a new line right before -w

Comment: _"what exactly is causing a new line"_ – where do the interpolated variables `file_name` and `src_port` come from? If you are reading them via `gets`, they might contain a trailing newline (use [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-chomp) to remove it). In either way you should escape the variables, see [Shellwords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html).

Comment: Printing the command (instead of executing it) could also help to find the cause, i.e. `puts "tshark -r #{file_name}.pcapng ..."`

Comment: No I didn't read them via    `gets` . I seem to have fixed my issue by simply doing    `stream = stream.chomp` . And yeah, now when I print the command it is all in the same line, printing the version before    `chomp` , I can see that it goes to a new line right after    `-w` . Thanks!

Comment: If `stream.chomp` solved your issue, you probably don't have `stream = "0xb6143376"` as shown in your example ...

Answer (score 0):

```
stream = stream.chomp
```

fixed my issue